# Direct limit in the category of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, field-theory, limits-colimits

> Is it true that the direct limit of a directed system in the category of fields is just the union of fields in the system with obvious maps?

I think its true but i am confused because i am new to category theory. Any ideas?

Comment: Not only category theory but also Universal Algebra can provide an answer to your question, the latter being "less general" in a sense, so that your question would be easier to answer from this point of view. In Grätzer's *Universal Algebra*, the direct limit of any directed system of algebras (fields are a certain type of algebras) is described. It is in fact the quotient space of the union, with a certain equivalence relation, namely $x\sim y$ if and only if there exist $i,j,k,z$ such that $i, j\leq k$, $x\in A_i, y\in A_j, z \in A_k$ with $f_{ik}(x) = f_{jk}(y) = z$, with obvious notations

Comment: @Max I always thought that _universal algebra_ was about _equational theories_ (what is modelled by Lawvere theories in the categorical style). How are fields models of an equational theory ? How do you handle the axiom "$x \neq 0 \implies \exists y. xy=yx=1$" with only equational ones ?

Comment: Pece : field aren't models of any equational theory (it follows from Birkhoff's theorem that equational classes, aka varieties, are exactly those classes that are stable by product, homorphic images, and subalgebras; whereas fields obviously aren't stable by products. But Universal Algebra studies algebras in general, not only the equationally definable ones (otherwise, how could there be such a theorem ?). To stress this point, in Grätzer's book, there's barely been any mention of equations when limits are introduced

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct.  If $\{K_\alpha\}$ is a directed system, we can show that $K = \bigcup_\alpha K_\alpha$ has the universal property of a direct limit: if $L$ is any field, then a collection of compatible morphisms $f_\alpha : K_\alpha \to L$ lifts uniquely to a morphism $f: K\to L$.

To see this, note that any $a\in K$ comes from some $a_\alpha \in K_\alpha$, so we must have $f(a) = f_\alpha (a_\alpha)$.  Once we have shown that this is really a well-defined (independent of $\alpha$) homomorphism of fields with the desired property, this gives us uniqueness. (Exercise: Fill in the details!)

One important note: It is easy to casually write $K = \bigcup_\alpha K_\alpha$, but we have to understand that this is a very specific kind of union, a *directed union*.  We cannot just throw together the various $K_\alpha$, since they are not given as part of a larger set.  Rather, we need to take the disjoint union and identify pairs that are compatible in the directed system.  (This is the direct limit in the category of sets.)

Comment: Slade's answer overlooks the fact that the disjoint union of fields cannot in general be given a field structure.

Comment: @SixWingedSeraph I took a disjoint union of _sets_, not fields.

Comment: @Slade: I am facing trouble in verifying the well definedness,could you please add some more details?

Comment: @MathLover Hint: If $a_\alpha = a_\beta$ in the directed union, then $a_\alpha \in K_\alpha$ and $a_\beta\in K_\beta$ are compatible in the directed system.  What does "compatible" mean?